# Unity: Building for ios and accessing the CSV file

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I have a simple app that collects user info such as name, email , job etc.. Im saving all of this info on the machine locally in this case the IPAD. This app will not be published as all uses will only work on 1 tablet. My questions is, How can i access this CSV file and open it manually after all users are done? I basically want to open the file and look at the info, but i can't find the csv file anywhere. Im using Application.datapersistantdatapath on Unity. Im using Unity and building to MAC, it's working perfectly on a windows machine.

The debug on the IPAD returns for me the path where the file is saved, now i need to open the file manually but i can't get to the path. How is it possible? the path is something like /var/mobile/containers/Data....

Answer (score 0):

`Application.persistantDataPath` is a string, what does it tell you if you try and print it?

Comment: it returns for me the path, i know that. My question is i can't open that path in the ipad itself...

Comment: it's giving me the path but now how do i open it?